# ???? Вместо русского текста PHP

Tags: php

При выводе данных из файла вместо русского текста знаки вопроса

```php
<?php
//echo file_get_contents( "file.txt" );
echo mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents( "file.txt" ), 'UTF-8');
    ?>
```

Содержимое файла `file.txt` :

> Я УЧУ PHP!

Comment: Проверьте кодировку как у файла `file.txt`, так и у вашего php-скрипта? Посмотрите также, какая кодировка по-умолчанию используется у вас для PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Укажите кодировку utf-8 через header

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
echo file_get_contents("file.txt");
```